# how to get yes if the user tick the single check box and no if he did not tick it in HTML

Tags: html, checkbox

I wrote on a contact form and in that there is a check box. What I want is if the user tick the check box I should get YES, and this I am getting,  no problem with that. What I also want is, if the user did not tick the check box I should get NO. How is this possible only in HTML? if not then in Java script? Note: I want to use only one check box. Below is the code for better understanding.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Agreed to Privacy Policy:" value="Yes" />
Please tick this check box if you agree with our 
<a href="http://www.xyz.com" target="_blank"> 
Privacy Policy</a></td>
```

Note: Right now I am getting in my test email if the check box is ticked is this:
 "Agreed to Privacy Policy: Yes"   What I want is if the user did not tick the check box "Agreed to Privacy Policy: No" . Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: You should be more objective in your question.

Comment: What language are you writing in to pick up the form data? You should be reading the POST information there from your form and then determining a YES/NO against the checkstate of the checkbox.

Comment: I have voted to close this question, due to comments made by the OP to my answer. It is apparently a "private" CMS system, which the OP either cannot edit or doesn't have the ability to edit.  @user, asking about client-side issues when the actual problem is in an unknown server-side environment is not going to help us or you

Answer (score 1):

A `<input type="checkbox">` will only return a value via the `<form>` if the checkbox has been ticked. Therefore you will never get a direct response from the checkbox if it hasn't been ticked.

The trick is to check whether ANY value has been passed as part of the POST/GET data.  If it has then the checkbox has been ticked... if it hasn't, it hasn't.

You do not provide any code or even a hint at the language you're using to send your email, but if you were using C# (for instance) you could use something like this...

(The following assumes you change the `name` attribute to something more appropriate like `chkAgree`, as having spaces in there is not going to help you)

```
messageBody += "Agreed to Privacy Policy: ";
messageBody += (Request["chkAgreed"] != null ? "Yes" : "No");
```

---

**Update**

Following on from the comment by the OP, here is the PHP version of the above code.

This assumes the `<form>` is using `method="post"`.  If you are using `method="get"` (or no `method` attribute at all) then you should change the `$_POST` into `$_GET`.

```
messageBody .= "Agreed to Privacy Policy: ";
messageBody .= (isset($_POST["chkAgreed"]) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Comment: I am using a private CMS to get the mail developed in PHP/MySQL to manage a website. And yes it is a form on the website where I wrote the above check box code. The form is working perfectly fine. What I want is if the user did not tick the check box "Agreed to Privacy Policy: No"

Comment: @user, does this `private CMS` allow you to alter the PHP code?  Because if it does, you haven't read my answer properly. Telling us about the client-side HTML is only part of your question, you should have told us about the server-side from the very start

Comment: It is a complex CMS, I do not understand the code of it. So it is difficult to make some changes in that PHP code, because there is no single php page for that form. as you can see the url of my form if you browse the site  looks like this: http://xyz.com/index.php?module=form&formId=5# and when i change the HTML code in the CMS from the browser it looks like this: http://xyz.com/admin/index.php?moduleId=30&action=edit&id=5.  Yes i agree with you about the name attribute, having spaces is not good. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user, if you cannot edit the PHP, there is no way anybody on SO is going to be able to help with a completely unknown (and unnamed) CMS. Unless you provide a **lot** more information, then I will not help anymore